# Check for variable being set to specific value during debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, variables, conditional-statements, breakpoints

In Visual Studio 2008, how do I have the code stop at my breakpoint only when a variable is at a specific value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to Specify a breakpoint condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)